# Group by the header that have identical value and list of details in it

Tags: c#, linq

I have this model:

```
public class HeaderDetail
{
   public Header Header { get; set}
   public Detail Detail{ get; set}
}
```

And a collection of it that contains a header with the same values:

```
public IEnumerable = new List<HeaderDetail>
{
   new HeaderDetail
   {
      new Header { HeaderID = 1, HeaderName = "One" },
      new Detail { DetailID = 1, HeaderID = 1, DetailName = "DetailOne" }
   },
   new HeaderDetail
   {
      new Header { HeaderID = 1, HeaderName = "One" },
      new Detail { DetailID = 2, HeaderID = 1, DetailName = "DetailTwo" }
   },
   new HeaderDetail
   {
      new Header { HeaderID = 2, HeaderName = "Two" },
      new Detail { DetailID = 3, HeaderID = 2, DetailName = "DetailThree" }
   },
}
```

Now, how can I group that list by the Header so they don't have duplication? New collection should have a model like this:

```
public class HeaderDetails
{
   public Header Header { get; set}
   public IEnumerable<Detail> Details{ get; set}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `GroupBy(a => a.Header.HeaderName).Select(a=>a.FirstOrDefault())` for grouping and removing duplicates

```cs
var data = new List<HeaderDetail>()
                {
                   new HeaderDetail
                   {
                    Header =  new Header { HeaderID = 1, HeaderName = "One" },
                    Detail =  new Detail { DetailID = 1, HeaderID = 1, DetailName = "DetailOne" }
                   },
                   new HeaderDetail
                   {
                     Header =  new Header { HeaderID = 1, HeaderName = "One" },
                     Detail =  new Detail { DetailID = 2, HeaderID = 1, DetailName = "DetailTwo" }
                   },
                   new HeaderDetail
                   {
                    Header =   new Header { HeaderID = 2, HeaderName = "Two" },
                    Detail =   new Detail { DetailID = 3, HeaderID = 2, DetailName = "DetailThree" }
                   }
                };
var groupedByHeaderName = data.GroupBy(a => a.Header.HeaderName).Select(a=>a.FirstOrDefault());
```

or only group by header name:

```cs
var groupedByHeaderName = data.GroupBy(a => a.Header.HeaderName, (key, val) => new { HeaderName = key, Data = val.ToList() });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = list.GroupBy(
            p => p.Header.HeaderName,
            p => p.Detail,
            (key, g) => new HeaderDetails { Header = new Header { HeaderName = key }, Details = g.ToList() });


        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Header.HeaderName);
            foreach (var det in item.Details)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(det.DetailName);
            }
        }
```